# Mobile menu not working on wordpress zerif theme

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, mobile, wordpress-theming

I have the zerif theme from themeisle installed on my wordpress and the menu isn't working on mobile. I have already contacted their support but they couldn't figure out the problem either. The menu works fine, but if you scroll the page and try to open it, it doesn't show anything. The menu seems to show normally and the console shows no erros. I have already disabled all the plugins and the juicer.io widget, but the problem continues anyway. This is the website url: http://ribeirojjuberlandia.com.br
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B'coz of you set fix height 50px inside `#main-nav.fixed` in style.css (line no:1829)

So you need to use `#main-nav.fixed{height: 100%;} or #main-nav.fixed{height: auto%;}`

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarifications.

Comment: that's awesome, it worked! the menu wouldn't be fixed though, but I added a wrap div with a position fixed and now it works perfectly. thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

add this css style

```
#main-nav.fixed {
    height: auto !important;
}
```